# How do I make my laptop use its discrete graphics card instead of its integrated graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card

I have an Alienware 14 laptop. In all games I try to play, it is using the integrated graphics card and not the Nvidia Geforce GTX 765m graphics card. I've gone to the Nvidia control panel and changed it to use the high performance Nvidia processor but it still uses the integrated graphics card.

Comment: It happens on all of the games i play

Comment: What happens? It uses the integrated video card? How do you know? What does it do? Please add more detail to your question. If this is happening to all games, though, it's a sure bet its your computer, not the games.

Comment: I know that this is happening because when i go to system specs it show me that it is using the integrated graphics card and not the nvidia graphics card. I should be able to run these games on high image a quality settings but when i do this i get a maximum of 15 fps. Ive tried the nvidia control panel and set it to high proformance nvidia processor but it still does the same thing. I dont know how to fix so thats why i came here.

Comment: What exactly did you change in the NVIDIA panel? There is a page that lets you change graphics card for individual programs, but I can't be sure if that's what you were referring to.

Comment: You install the OEM drivers for both devices.  This will allow you switch between which CPU will be used.

Comment: Related: [How can I make windows 8 to ignore integrated graphics and only “see” the dedicated GPU?](http://superuser.com/q/504727/10259) and [How do I prevent my laptop from switching to the integrated graphic card when it is not charging](http://superuser.com/q/630723/10259)

Answer (score -1):

user@linuxbox ~ $ optirun application

integrated, dedicated gpu switching is done by project bumblebee in linux platform. also for the auto switching there is project primus. If you wanna use auto-switch rather than VirtualGL you need to run  $ primusrun application.

http://bumblebee-project.org/